# Reduce the size of a Powerpoint while keeping image quality

Tags: image-quality, microsoft-powerpoint

Are there any additional options for reducing the size of a Powerpoint presentation without losing image quality?

I've got a deck that is approximately 25 slides, 15 of which have images. The deck ends up being over 25 MB. I would like to possibly cut that in half.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you you have Photoshop available?

Comment: Do you know the resolution (ppi) of the images?

Answer (score 1):

You won't have much luck. PPT doesn't seem to be very efficient with it's file size in my experience.

That said, I've been able to bring file size down on a good day by applying the same principles you would for a web page. Optimize the images as best you can and then reimport them. The quality is completely relative so push the limit on compression based on your end use.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem are scaled pictures. **Resizing** the images **before embedding** them into your Powerpoint to the final size can make a big difference. And while you are at scaling you could try out **jpg compression**, but there will always be a certain loss of quality.